# Creating PDF with PhantomJSCloud

Tags: php, pdf, phantomjs

Right now im using the following code to create a PDF

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
$baseLink = 'http://myphantomjsurl/single/browser/v1/v1regression/';
$targetLink = 'http://myurl/view_appointment.html';
$link .=$baseLink.'?requestType=pdf&targetUrl='.$targetLink ;
$CurlConnect = curl_init();
curl_setopt($CurlConnect, CURLOPT_URL, $link);
curl_setopt($CurlConnect, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
$Result = curl_exec($CurlConnect);
echo $link;
echo $Result;
?>
```

I always get a ERROR 404: CONTENT NOT
FOUND.

**The page has exactly the same content as http://www.example.com and when I change my url with http://www.example.com it works.**

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: it works for simple .html files but if I have a php file with simple

```
echo "<span>test</span>";
```

it does not work.

Comment: Have you fixed the `404` ?